# Automated data extraction from a certain parts of a screenshot

Tags: extract, automated-deployment

I work with an EMR (epic) that is stingy with API, which is understandable given HIPPA and whatsoever.

In my work, I generate a table in note editor, that has certain blood values. I manually enter these numbers in a separate custom made calculator to get certain values.

I do this process a lot during the day which is a cumbersome routine.

Is there a way to extract the text data and put them in the online calculator?

Since maybe there is no way to get the text directly to a calculator, here are my thoughts:

1. Create a script that asks me to highlight the table, then it transfers the data to the calculator by itself and do the calculations.
2. Take a screenshot, and train the model to identify tables and extract the data ..etc.

The table of interest looks like this:

Extracting texts from images. But wants from a specific area with auto assembly into certain values